# Creating Lights On Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm working on writing code for a game called Lights On where the idea of the game is to produce a board of randomly lit squares and to win all squares must be lit (1 is on 0 is off). Clicking on a square inverts that square and any squares neighboring it above, below, left, or right. However, I am having trouble inverting the board correctly using my code bellow

```
import time # provides time.sleep(0.5)
from csplot import choice
from random import * # provides choice( [0,1] ), etc.
import sys  # larger recursive stack
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) # 100,000 deep

def runGenerations2d(L , x = 0,y=0):
    show(L)
    print( L )           # display the list, L
    time.sleep(.1)      # pause a bit
    newL = evolve2d( L )   # evolve L into newL
    print(newL)
    if min(L) == 1:
    #I like read outs to be explained so I added an extra print command.
        if x<=1: # Takes into account the possibility of a 1 click completition.
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i click to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        else:
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i clicks to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        return   
    x = x+1 # add 1 to x before every recusion
    runGenerations2d( newL , x,y )  # recurse

def evolve2d( L ):    
    N = len(L)  
    x,y = sqinput2()
    return [[ setNewElement2d( L, i, j,x,y ) for i in range(N)]for j in range(N) ]

def setNewElement2d( L, i, j, x=0, y=0 ):
    if y==j and (i == x-1 or i == x+1 or i ==x):
        return 1-L[i][j] 
    elif x==i and (j == y-1 or j == y+1):  
        return 1-L[i][j] 
    else:
        return L[i][j]
```

I believe the issue is with my setNewElement2d function, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where it does not invert correctly? preferably a small example. :-)

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of the parameters `x` and `y` in `runGenerations2d()`? I think I can figure out `x` (though it seems poorly named, if so) but `y` isn't used and doesn't change.

Comment: I hope you have a typo on that output; I get [1,0,0] on the last line after you select?

Comment: Odd. When I run this, I get `[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]` as the result of choosing the position (0,2). I'm not using your plotting library, though (no idea what `csplot` is; I'm just inputting data and printing out the result). Are we talking about the same thing? All the same, the answer I just submitted should remain valid.

Comment: Edit: Actually, I wonder if the difference we're seeing in result isn't a similar error, done again somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to explain why you deleted the question?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You've swapped i and j in `evolve2d()`.

Long answer: When `evolve2d()` creates the new matrix, `i` needs to be in the outer loop, not the inner loop. Else, swap `i` and `j`. For example, if I change the call to

```
return [[ setNewElement( L, j, i, x, y ) for i in range(N) ] for j in range(N) ]
```

then I get the correct answer for your example.

This has to do with the organization of a two-dimensional array. In Python, `L[i][j]` looks in the ith row (vertical count down) and the jth column (horizontal count right). But you want `i` to compare to the `x` value, which in your mind is horizontal. So the point you're testing against has its coordinates swapped from the points you think you're testing against.

*Last edit, I swear:* Basically, the program did exactly what it was supposed to do. But when you looked at it, you imagined `x` and `y` to have the traditional meanings (horizontal and vertical, respectively) when in the array they have the opposite meanings: `L[x][y]` looks **down** `x` rows and **right** `y` columns.

Comment: When I enter the array `[[1,1,0], [1,1,1], [1,0,0]]` and select (0,2) for `(x,y)`, the revised code (which you list below -- only one line changed, right?) gives `[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`. This agrees with the specifications you gave for the game. If this isn't what you want, please clarify the expectations. If this isn't what you're getting, then I submit that you are not thinking carefully enough about the explanation I gave. For example, in the example you gave earlier, where you and I had different results,  you had clearly reversed the x values somewhere along the line.